# Ошибка 1335 при установке JDK

Tags: java

При установке JKD 7 получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто встречал и знает решение?
Чистка реестра, отключение антивируса, фаервола и т.д. Результата не принесло.
Прогонял систему утилитой FixIt результата тоже нет.
Система Windows 10 на Windows 8.1 такая же ошибка.

Comment: У вас же ясно написано, что файл испорчен.

Comment: @Visman все файлы JDK на Oracle испорчены? Пробовал JDK 6,8

Comment: Вирусы, антивирусы, проактивные защиты файрволов, что еще может повлиять на файл?